# writing info to csv in python

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from urlparse import urljoin
import urllib2

base_url = 'http://www.baseball-reference.com/' # base url for concatenation
data = requests.get("http://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BAL/2014-schedule-scores.shtml") #website for scraping
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.content)
b=5

for link in soup.find_all('a'):

    if not link.has_attr('href'):
        continue

    if link.get_text() != 'boxscore':
        continue

    url = base_url + link['href']

    response = requests.get(url)
    html = response.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    # Scores
    table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'BaltimoreOriolespitching'})
    for row in table.findAll('tr'):
        list_of_cells = []
        for cell in row.findAll('td'):
            text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
            list_of_cells.append(text)
        for list in list_of_cells:
            with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                a.writerows(list)
```

I am trying to write the info scraped to a csv so that each piece of information has its own cell. The more I play with the code I either get an indentation error or the first row prints to a csv and thats it.

IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: What, specifically, errors are you getting?

Comment: IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Most likely you have a whitespace error. Check that all of your whitespace are either equal to tabstops(not recommended) or that every indentation level matches exactly four spaces(recommended)

Comment: Also, if you continue to get the indentation error, please indicate what the line number is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the first thing to consider is moving opening the file and creating the CSV writer outside the loop. I think you're overwriting the CSV file (`'w'`) on each pass through the `for` loop. So try this:

```
with open('test1.csv', 'w', newline='') as fp:
    csvw = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):

        if not link.has_attr('href'):
            continue

        if link.get_text() != 'boxscore':
            continue

        url = base_url + link['href']

        response = requests.get(url)
        html = response.content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

        # Scores
        table = soup.find('table', attrs={'id': 'BaltimoreOriolespitching'})
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            list_of_cells = []
            for cell in row.findAll('td'):
                text = cell.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
                list_of_cells.append(text)
            for list in list_of_cells:
                    csvw.writerows(list)
```